# jQuery UI dialog - As soon as I add a second Dialog to the App, it breaks?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have add a jQuery UI Dialog to my Rails 3 web app as follows:

```
 permissions = $('<div id="dialog-content"></div>')
.html('<div class="notification"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>')
.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    dialogClass: 'dialog',
    width: 460,
    minHeight: 80,
    position: ['center',130],
    open: function() {
        $.ajax({url: '/stuff/'})
    },
    close: function() {
        $('#dialog-content').html('<div class="notification"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>');
    }       
});

$(".teammember-dialog").live("click",function(){
    permissions.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

What's puzzling to me is I just added another dialog to my app as follows:

```
 dialogstuff2 = $('<div id="dialog-content"></div>')
.html('<div class="notification"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>')
.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    dialogClass: 'dialog',
    width: 460,
    minHeight: 80,
    position: ['center',130],
    open: function() {
        $.ajax({url: '/stuff/'})
    },
    close: function() {
        $('#dialog-content').html('<div class="notification"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>');
    }       
});

$("#addlink").live("click",function(){
    dialogstuff2.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

With the 2nd dialog, it breaks both dialogs. They both open but they don't respond to the JS that is loaded when the dialog calls the webserver. If I remove the 2nd one the first works fine. But when both are on the page, when I click to load either, the dialog stands still with the default loading text "loading..."

Anyone seen this before? thanks

Answer (score 4):

One thing that I notice in your code is both the dialogs have an outer div with an id of `dialog-content`. You may want to make them different and see what happens as the browser/jQuery may not like that.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be a problem. But having different IDs doesn't seem very DRY? Is there a way to make it work with the same ID so things don't get crazy messy as my app will likely have multiple dialogs?... Also many of the Dialog settings are the same, is there a way to set that for all dialogs, and just add the custom dialog attributes like post URL per dialog?

Comment: With regards to DRY, the ID is meant to be unique in a page so the browser and jQuery will take advantage of that for performance and maybe other reasons. Maybe making the ID reflect the purpose of the dialog will help? As for global settings I dare say it's possible with a little wrapper function, however that is best posed as a separate question as my Javascript is still quite novice :)

Comment: the DRY principal is best handled in JavaScript by creating wrapper methods, builders or factories as @a,arsuperstar mentioned. I have answered below with some methods that illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is where good old classic software engineering comes in handy with the JavaScript. Make a dialog builder method that utilizes an internal unique identifier to create the dialog sets you want.

```
function dialogBuilder(url){
  var uuid = 0;
  var name = 'dialog_' + uuid++;
  var $elem = $('<div id="' + name + '"></div>')
  .html('<div class="notification"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>')
  .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    dialogClass: 'dialog',
    width: 460,
    minHeight: 80,
    position: ['center',130],
    open: function() {
      $.ajax({url: '/stuff/'})
    },
    close: function() {
      $('#dialog-content').html('<div class="notification"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>');
    }       
  });
  return $elem;
}
var permissions = dialogBuilder('/stuff/');
var dialogstuff = dialogBuilder('/stuff/');
```

You get the idea, the next obvious step would be to establish the names outside so you could do something like this:

```
var dialogHandler = {};
function dialogBuilder(dname, url, anchor){
  var uuid = 0;
  var name = 'dialog_' + dname;
  if(dialogHandler[name]){
    var $elem = dialogHandler[name].dialog({open:function(){$.ajax(url)}});
    dialogHandler[name] = $elem;
  }else{
    var $elem = $('<div id="' + name + '"></div>')
    .html('<div class="notification"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>')
    .dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      dialogClass: 'dialog',
      width: 460,
      minHeight: 80,
      position: ['center',130],
      open: function() {
        $.ajax({url: '/stuff/'})
      },
      close: function() {
        $('#dialog-content').html('<div class="notification"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>');
      }       
    });
    dialogHandler[name] = $elem;
  }
  $(anchor).live('click',function(){
    dialogHandler[name].dialog('open');
    return false;
  })
}

// to call this above code:
dialogBuilder('dialogstuff2','/stuff/','#addlink');
dialogBuilder('permissions','/stuff/','.teammember-dialog');
```

written but not tested.